# Irreducible $S_n$-modules and $S_n$-actions on projective spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, modules, projective-geometry, induced-representations

Let $V$ be an $(N+1)$-dimensional vector space with an action of the symmetric group $S_n$, such that $V$ is an irreducible $S_n$ -module.

Let $\{p_1,...,p_h\}\in \mathbb{P}(V)$ be $h\geq N+2$ points such that $S_n$ acts transitively on $\{p_1,...,p_h\}$.

Is it true then that there exist $N+2$ points $p_{i_1},...,p_{i_{N+2}}\in \{p_1,...,p_h\}$ that are in linear general position in $\mathbb{P}(V)$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**:  Actually, I made this way too difficult.

Points in projective space are in general linear position if the corresponding lines are the multiples of a basis of $V$.  Thus, the question is just if the lines corresponding to $p_1,\dots, p_h$ span the vector space $V$ (since in this case, some subset will correspond to a basis).  The span of these lines is invariant and non-zero, and so must be all of $V$ by its irreducibility.

Comment: You seem to assume $h=N+2$, aren't you?

Comment: Another problem is that the $S_n$-action on the lines $\{p_i\}$ does not need to lift to an action on points in $V$ representing these lines. That is, for each $i$ and each $\sigma \in S_n$, there exist an index $j$ and a scalar $\lambda$ such that $\sigma(p_i) = \lambda p_j$. If this scalar is not $1$, the $S_n$-action does not even map $(p_i,1)$ to a $(p_j,1)$ (nor a multiple of this).

Comment: @ThiKu No.  A set contains a basis if and only if it spans.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn See my edits.  I just assumed readers could do a little basic linear algebra....

Comment: If $g \cdot v_i = \lambda v_j$, then $g \cdot (v_i,1) = (\lambda v_j, 1)$. If $\lambda \neq 1$, then why is this in the span of the $(v_j, 1)$? E.g. the vector $(-v,1)$ is not a scalar multiple of $(v,1)$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I see now that I had gotten myself mixed up between projective and affine spaces.  Luckily, that just means the proof was easier.

Comment: @BenWebster: I think that's also not quite right. A set in general position should have one more element than a basis. The representation I know is that a set in general position can be written as $e_i$, $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ for a suitable basis; it's easy to get your $(v_i,1)$ description from that.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I'm just going on Wikipedia's definition, which says "Similarly, n vectors in an n-dimensional vector space are linearly independent if and only if the points they define in projective space (of dimension n-1) are in general linear position."

Comment: @ BenWebster --- at first, I thought the problem is indeed as trivial as you suggest, but this is not what the question is asking. The goal is to show that we can find N+2 points in general position among those given in the N-dimensional projective space. Here being in general position means that removing any one of them still leaves a spanning set. For example, if N=2, we need four points on a plane such that no three of them are collinear.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: to me, it seems that adding the trivial representation is simply about restating general position in V considered as an affine space as a general position in the linear space $(V\oplus C)$. (Or if you like, $V$ as an affine space is considered as a subset in the projective space of lines in $V\oplus C$.) Since the question already asks about projective space corresponding to V, this does not seem to be related...

Comment: @t3suji I agree with this.  In particular, two distinct multiples of each other will give a basis after adding the trivial rep, since the points are affinely independent, but obviously don't even give distinct points in projective space.

Comment: @t3suji, Ben Webster: My apologies; it seems that that criterion was unrelated indeed.